# Typescript - define an object type with some specific known properties, and an undefined number of unknown properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a type using the following code, which isn't allowed:

```
type ValidationResult {
  [key: string]: ValidationResult;
  isValid: boolean;
  errors?: string[];
}
```

Hopefully it's obvious what I'm trying to achieve. I want a ValidationResult to have one isValid property which is a boolean, one errors property which is an array of strings, and any number of additional properties which are ValidationResults.

Can anyone advise on correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface A {
  valid: boolean;
}

type All = A & Record<string, ValidationResult>;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question 
improves its long-term value. Consider reading [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit] your answer to improve it.